# how to tell whether a string contain a specific amount of characters with Array?

Tags: java

one of my homework problem is

> Define a   method  named   countAll    that    accepts a   String  as  an  argument.The    method  must
>   return  an  array   of  int of  size    27, such    that    the value   in  position    0   is  a   count   of  the number  of
>   ‘a’ and ‘A’ characters  in  the input,  the value   in  position    1   is  a   count   of  the number  of  ‘b’ and 
>   ‘B’ characters  in  the input,  …   the value   in  position    25  is  a   count   of  the number  of  ‘z’ and ‘Z’ characters  in  the input,  and the value   in  position    26  is  a   count   of  all the non-alphabetic
>   characters  in  the input.

i tried solving it with

```
public static int[] countAll(String input){
        int[] ints = new int[27];
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
                if(input.charAt(i)=='a'||input.charAt(i)=='A'){
                    ints[0]+=1;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='B'||input.charAt(i)=='b'){
                    ints[1]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='c'||input.charAt(i)=='C'){
                    ints[2]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='d'||input.charAt(i)=='D'){
                    ints[3]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='e'||input.charAt(i)=='E'){
                    ints[4]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='f'||input.charAt(i)=='F'){
                    ints[5]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='g'||input.charAt(i)=='G'){
                    ints[6]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='h'||input.charAt(i)=='H'){
                    ints[7]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='I'||input.charAt(i)=='i'){
                    ints[8]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='j'||input.charAt(i)=='J'){
                    ints[9]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='K'||input.charAt(i)=='k'){
                    ints[10]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='l'||input.charAt(i)=='L'){
                    ints[11]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='m'||input.charAt(i)=='M'){
                    ints[12]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='n'||input.charAt(i)=='N'){
                    ints[13]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='o'||input.charAt(i)=='O'){
                    ints[14]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='p'||input.charAt(i)=='P'){
                    ints[15]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='q'||input.charAt(i)=='Q'){
                    ints[16]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='r'||input.charAt(i)=='R'){
                    ints[17]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='s'||input.charAt(i)=='S'){
                    ints[18]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='T'||input.charAt(i)=='t'){
                    ints[19]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='U'||input.charAt(i)=='u'){
                    ints[20]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='V'||input.charAt(i)=='v'){
                    ints[21]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='W'||input.charAt(i)=='w'){
                    ints[22]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='x'||input.charAt(i)=='X'){
                    ints[23]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='y'||input.charAt(i)=='Y'){
                    ints[24]++;
                }
                if(input.charAt(i)=='z'||input.charAt(i)=='Z'){
                    ints[25]++;
                }

            }
        return ints;
    }

}
```

but that's unrealistic approach to the problem.

so i want to know how to shorten the codes inside the for loop and how should i solve the part with special character.

Comment: Your task seems to talk about mapping the number of occurences of each letter to a certain index of an array, maybe that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Use the numeric representation of the char value to simplify. Google for any [ASCII table](http://ascii-code.com/) to find these values.

a-z (lowercase) is 97 - 122.

So first convert the string to **all lowercase** then, for example:

```
if(charVal >= 97 && charVal <= 122){
    ints[charVal - 97]++;
    // The -97 gives you an array index of 0 through 25.
}
else {
    // Otherwise it's not a-z.
    ints[26]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is clearly an homework, it would not be helpful for anyone to give you a silver plated answer. But here are some insight on how to optimize.

In Java, a character may be a numeric value. For instance `str.charAt(0) - 'a'` will return a numeric value, where `0` is `a` and `25` is `z`. (**Note:** there *is* a difference between `"a"` and `'a'`; one is a `String`, the other is a `char`.) You'll also want to `str.toLowerCase()` your string, as `'a' != 'A'`.)

Then, all you need to do is loop through all the characters of the string, get the character value (i.g. the array index) and increment your array. If the character value is less than `0` or greater than `25`, then your character value is `26`.

**Hint:** `for (char c : input.toCharArray()) { ... }`

Comment: This is the right answer for a homework question. +1